# Remove Trailing slashes from all URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I used the following rule Remove Trailing slashes from all URL

```
#remove /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

the rule is working fine expect for home page /

its through

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

i've enabled mod_ rewrite logs to trace the rule

```
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)\\/(\\?.*)?$' to uri '/'
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (2) rewrite '/' -> ''
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.mywebpage.com/
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (1) escaping http://www.mywebpage.com/ for redirect
10.64.159.12 - - [14/Feb/2018:12:04:16 +0400] [www.mywebpage.com/sid#7effdd821860][rid#7eff00068100/initial] (1) redirect to http://www.mywebpage.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

any idea why its not working for home page url  and works for all other pages  url

Comment: try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L] `

Comment: its not working and its throiugh ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for all urls now ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove trailing slash keep this rule **your first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```